# What is Inara's backstory?

Tags: firefly, character-development

It's hinted at a few times in *Firefly* that Inara, like most of the crew, has an interesting past. Most notably, see the following conversation between Mal and Nandi in episode 13, "Heart of Gold":

> NANDI:  She ever tell you why she left Sihnon?
>
> MAL:  Never asked.
>
> NANDI:  Yes, you did. And I don't know, my own self. I was gone long
>   before. And I'll tell you, it was a shock, her leaving. She was
>   special. There's 40 women in House Madrassa and you'd pick her out in
>   a second. Coulda been House Priestess, few years time.
>
> MAL:  Is that right?
>
> NANDI:  Had her eyes on it too. Very focused. She's like you, more than
>   a little.

Shepherd Book's backstory [has been revealed in other canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/166/31394), so maybe the same goes for Inara?

### What is Inara's backstory? Is it ever revealed?

Comment: There _are_ future works in the same 'Verse with the same crew - I believe there's a new comic series inbound, and one has been published throughout 2017. They keep revealing backstories - e.g. there was one about Wash and Shepherd Book - so there may as well be one about Inara in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Some clues in the series suggest she might be seriously ill, maybe dying. One conversation in particular, where Jayne (?) Says he "doesn't want to die like this" Inara replies she just doesn't want to die.

Comment: Her not wanting to die implies she's ill or dying? Could it not just be that she fears death?

Comment: @Edlothiad Nah I think she's really supposedly dying from something. Take a look at this YouTube discussion clip with Morena Baccarin - https://youtu.be/YTxGOi9coWQ

Comment: I could have sworn there was another bit in the series or movie implying she had an illness.

Comment: Don't we see her give herself an injection at one point?

Comment: Morena confirmed in a 'con panel that Inara was dying of a terminal illness. The only hint was the above, which occurred in the episode 'Out of Gas'.

Comment: In the pilot, when they're worrying about Reavers, we briefly see that Inara has a syringe that seems important.  Some fans speculated that the syringe was for suicide, but (iirc) Whedon says no.